# About the command window in arduino

Tags: arduino

I have been using Arduino UNO micro controller for my project. I would like to know how can I open a window to type, for example, char "C" to do what I have assigned it to do. For example the following code.

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo servothumb; 

int command; int x =1;

// Define thumb servo
void setup() {
Serial.begin (115200);
servothumb.attach(2); // Set thumb servo to digital pin 2
}

void loop() {
if(Serial.available() > 0){ 
     command = Serial.read(); 
       if (command == 'c'){}
}
close();
delay(4000); }

void close() { 
  servothumb.write(0);

}
```

Comment: I think you're better here: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a serial terminal program, on the com port. So, in windows you might use Putty.exe, for example, and configure it to run on com1, or whatever com port your Arduino is attached to.